# How to use a button and a string variable to toggle an add and remove event listener for tow dropdown lists

Tags: javascript

Good evening guys,

I have a click button and two drop down lists.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="my-select-one">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

for dropdown `my-select` I have an event listener that uses a variable called `ites` which is set to `'my-select'`to get the dropwdown element by id and listen for the dropdown change. Then it runs some code if the dropdown is change.

```
document.getElementById(ites).addEventListener('change', function() {
//some code
});
```

The problem is I want it so that when the user clicks the button once they are able to remove the event listener from `my-select` and add it to the second dropdown `my-select-one`. I need to do this by changing the value of the variable `ites` thus so I can use the function for multiple other dropdowns without violating DRY principles. But its not working. Any ideas how to fix my code? See below the full Javascript file.

```
let ites = 'my-select';

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById(ites).removeEventListener('change', myFunction);
  ites = 'my-select-one';
console.log(ites);
}


document.getElementById(ites).addEventListener('change', function() {
  dropDownChangedOne = true;
  console.log(dropDownChangedOne);
  console.log(ites);
});
```

Comment: Is `myfunction()` the function for the button or the dropdown?

Comment: Why doesn't the event listener just use `this.id` to get the ID of the dropdown that was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the listener function for the dropdowns and for the button. I've given them more descriptive names below.

The listener on the button should check get the current value of `ites` and then swap it. It can remove and add the event listeners on the dropdowns.

```js
let ites = 'my-select';

function buttonFunction() {
  // remove old listener
  document.getElementById(ites).removeEventListener('change', dropdownFunction);
  // toggle variable
  ites = ites == 'my-select' ? 'my-select-one' : 'my-select';
  document.getElementById(ites).addEventListener('change', dropdownFunction);
}

document.getElementById('my-select').addEventListener('change', dropdownFunction);

function dropdownFunction() {
  console.log(`${ites} changed to ${this.value}`);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonFunction()">Click Me</button>

<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="my-select-one">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```